# raphael zoom out with grid - infinite paper size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, raphael, zooming

I am attempting to create a simple drawing package using Raphael.

For this example, I have defined a paper with a specific size that has a grid drawn to the edges of the paper .  In my actual application, the paper is set to the size of the div.

See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/davidbe/LhWZ5/

I'm using the  raphael.pan-zoom package to support zooming with the scroll wheel and panning with the left mouse button.

```
page = Raphael(graph_paper, 402, 602);
panZoom = page.panzoom({ initialZoom: 0, 
                        initialPosition: { x: 0, y: 0},
                        maxZoom: 30,
                        minZoom: -10});
panZoom.enable();
```

This works fine when I zoom in, but the problem I am having is that when I zoom out so that the Raphael paper is smaller than the div, the grid lines do not extend to the edge of the div.  I'm trying to figure out a way to have the grid lines always displayed to the edges of the div, regardless of my zoom setting.  In order to do this, I think that I either need to define a larger paper size when I create the paper so that when I zoom out, I am still seeing part of the original paper.  Alternatively, I may need to change the paper size as part of the zooming.  Either way, I don't want to see x and y scroll bars for the div.

Another way to look at this is that I am trying to simulate an infinite page size.  Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Comment: i think you mean zoom in, right? when you zoom in the gird gets bigger and edges disappear

Comment: I do mean zoom out.  When I zoom in, the gets bigger and some of the grid lines appear to fall off the edge.  This is expected by the user.  However, when I zoom out, once the full page is shown, as I zoom out further, I am left with a white border around the edge rather than more grid lines.